# Prevent dismissal of dialogfragment loaded with navigation component on touch outside

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-navigation

I've been using the `navigation component` to load all my views including dialog fragments. For some of them, I don't want them to be dismissable when the user touches outside.

Is there a flag I can pass to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that setting `isCancellable = false` will do the trick.

Comment: Where do you put the is cancellable ?

Comment: In your `DialogFragment's onStart` method.

Comment: Won't that be affected by the lifecycle of the fragment?